# Cannot resolve module index.js npm package

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to test a NPM package in my local (my own package). I followed this guide : http://rajasekarm.com/publishing-react-component-npm/

I have this in my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "build": "./node_modules/.bin/babel statbox.js -o index.js",
  "prepublish": "npm run build"
},
```

I committed this custom package in my git, and did an

`npm install 'url/url/my_sample.git' --save`

But when I do a:

`import myModule from 'my_sample'`

It says that `index.js`  is unresolved. How do I solve this one?

Answer (score 0):

If there's no *index.js* file, I suppose **you don't have built** (because `npm build` will translate your *statbox.js* to a *index.js*).

So run `npm build` and retest your package.